# How to add the time into msql when user submit a form?

Tags: php, database

I want to add the current time when the user has submitted the form in database?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the timestamp with PHP's `DateTime->setTimeStamp()` method.

For DateTime, use something like this

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp=$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Returns something like 2013-12-7 11:10:14
```

If you're looking to do this in MySQL as opposed to PHP, use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` method

Comment: BTW:
How can I change 2013-12-7 => 7-12-2013 (d-m-Y)?
And Also I don't need to echo seconds in my php

Something like this:
7-12-2013 11:10

Comment: Read up on  date formatting 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

use date() function of php to get the current time.

```
$adate=date("Y-m-d");
```

or you can use `NOW()` in mysql to insert the current time in mysql.